# RVIZ HECTOR SLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rviz, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HELLO...

Can anybody explain step by step how can ı do this project like video ???

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=pCF7P7u8pDk**

I have Rplidar ROS library.

**https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros**

and ı have RVIZ on ubuntu / indigo

nobody know as exactly .

İs anybody explain this project step by step on pictures or video.

ı AM DOİNG LİKE THİS :

$ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch $ roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch ( it is started RVIZ program)

this is working and starting publish lidar scan data. I added LASER_SCAN and MAP tools on RVIZ display.

if ı write Laser_Scan -> Topic "/scan" and GLobal Options -> fixed frame "laser" , I can see LIDAR data on RVİZ on rviz display.

BUT !!!! f ı write Laser_Scan -> Topic "/scan" and GLobal Options -> fixed frame "map" , I can NOT see LIDAR data on RVİZ on rviz display. and I see this error:

Transform [sender=unknown_publisher] For frame [laser]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
please solve this problem. help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209361/rviz-hector-slam/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest reading about the [Hector SLAM](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) from this page and how to set up for your robot or do laser sensor only mapping. Of course do the basic [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) first. Learning by doing is the best practice. Try first and if you fail ask the community for help. ROS tutorials and Hector SLAM has well written wiki page and tutorials for any beginner level ROS user to understand clearly and concisely.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-03**:
HI, I think those links are very basic. Can you give link to some better tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Problem is that you dont have a transform from laser to map, post your tf tree please:

```
rosrun tf view_frames

evince frames.pdf
```

---

Originally posted by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) with karma: 201 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-05-21**:
ı run your code and result:
"NO TF DATA RECEIVED"

my codes like this:
-$ roscore  (no error)
-$ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch    (RPLidar health status : 0)
-$ roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch (no error)

ı can see laser frame on rviz no map
what is the problem ı couldnt find .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

This is my blog but in Chinese.

There are steps about hector slam  in the article.

https://hollyqood.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/ros-slam-2-hector-slam-2d%E5%9C%B0%E5%9C%96%E5%BB%BA%E7%BD%AE/

I guess that was no laser data because of the com port permission.

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Please that me know if you  were success. :)

Alyson

---

Originally posted by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) with karma: 196 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-15**:
Thank you. I found this helpful!